# ffmpeg parallel encoding for make mp4 qualities

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to make the different qualities from video in one command.

I used this below code.

But there is an issue,and it's that the output files not have details

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]format=yuv420p,split=2[s0][s1]; 
[s0]scale=hd480[v0];
[s1]scale=nhd[v1] 
-map [v0] -map [v1] -map 0:a? -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f tee -threads 0  
"[select='v\:0,a':f=mp4]1/480.mp4|[select='v\:1,a':f=mp4]1/360.mp4"
```

What I must be do?

Comment: *not have details* --> unclear.

Comment: @Mulvya ? sorry,I didn't understand.Can you tell me what can I do?

Comment: Don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: @Mulvya there is no error,just created files in properties --> Details no have a video type info,no have width,height,length,rate,.....and with windows player doesn't play

Comment: What's the output of `ffprobe 480.mp4` and `ffprobe 360.mp4`?

Comment: @Mulvya for 360 this is it:

`Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1/360.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
  Duration: 00:04:12.12, start: 0.056009, bitrate: 606 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 470 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)`

Comment: @Mulvya for 480 :
`Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1/480.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
  Duration: 00:04:12.12, start: 0.056009, bitrate: 859 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 852x480, 723 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)`

Comment: @Mulvya In this case:
`ffmpeg -i 17939-68744129.mp4 -filter_complex [v:0]format=yu
v420p,split=6[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4][v5] -map 0:a? -map [v0] -c:v libx264 -c:a aac
-f mp4 -s uhd2160 4k.mp4 -map 0:a? -map [v1] -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f
 mp4 -s hd1080 1080.mp4 -map 0:a? -map [v2] -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f
mp4 -s hd720 720.mp4 -map [v3] -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f mp4 -s hd480 480.mp4 
-map 0:a? -map [v4] -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f mp4 -s nhd
 360.mp4 -map 0:a? -map [v5] -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f mp4 -s cga 200.mp4`
How can I set `-threads 0`?

Comment: ffprobe shows normal output. Does ffplay play the output?

Comment: @Mulvya ffplay plays the output,but files don't have headers and with the video player of windows 10 I have this message `This file isn't playable. That might be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt.` with `Cant play` title

Comment: Add `-flags +global_header` to your original tee command and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the guidances and helps of @Mulvya the answer is like this :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]format=yuv420p,split=2[s0][s1]; 
[s0]scale=hd480[v0];
[s1]scale=nhd[v1] 
-map [v0] -map [v1] -map 0:a? -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f tee -flags +global_header -threads 0  
"[select='v\:0,a':f=mp4]1/480.mp4|[select='v\:1,a':f=mp4]1/360.mp4"
```